# Facebook like button - onclick set cookie

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, fbml

i am making some Facebook "stuff" for my client and he wants that after clicking like cookie is set and for 24 hours this like box wont be seen. Don't ask my why :) 
So i have made function liked():

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function liked(){
   days=1; 
   myDate = new Date();
   myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
   document.cookie = 'liked=button; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();
}
```

But what I do not know is how to force facebook like button to call this function. I found some code on FB developers and this site too, but i dont know where to use it.

> FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
>       function(response) {
>           alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
>       } );

Could anyone please help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                    FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create", function(response) { alert("You liked the URL: " + response); } );
                    };</script>
```